# How to hold an keyboard key using pynput/pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

so basically i tried the following python script with both pyautogui and pynput (i will leave both codes below), what i want it to do is to hold the key "s" for 10 seconds, after that release it, but instead what it does is press the key once only, following is the code

**Pynput**

```
keyboard = Controller()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   keyboard.press("s")
   time.sleep(10)
   keyboard.release("s")
```

**Pyautogui**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyDown("s")
    time.sleep(10)
    keyUp("s")
```

thanks, and sorry for any incovinience

Comment: `keyboard.press("s")` does not mean what you think it does. Read the documentation.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions) on what `press` does vs `keyDown` and `keyUp`

Comment: @Jeremy in the example i give above i was using pynput not pyautogui, but even with pyautogui keyDown function it only does one click instead of holding down the key

Comment: @BoarGules i took a look at it, but i still dont know how to fix my issue, can you help me ?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes! that worked perfectly thank you so much i ll close the question now